# Strings.exe does not see Cyrillic

Tags: unicode, string, sysinternals

Sysinternals utility Strings.exe does not see Cyrillic strings despite the fact that it works with Unicode. Does exist any utilities or libraries that really can extract all printable Unicode strings from a binary file?

Comment: What does it not find Cyrillic strings in?

Comment: @RowlandShaw in everything. I've created file in utf8 with several lines in English and Russian and it returns only english.